# How do I print more than one enum value using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm not sure how to formulate the question but say I have a pizza with toppings, and I want (through the main class) to print or call to the description of this pizza that contains not one but two toppings, how should I do this?

My toppings class is an enum so I've tried, so far, this:

```
public class Pizza{

    private Toppings[] toppings;

    public Pizza(Toppings[] toppings){
        this.toppings = new Toppings[]{Toppings.tomatosauce, Toppings.cheese};
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Toppings: " + toppings;
    }

}
```

then in the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza(Toppings.cheese);
        System.out.println(pizza);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is wrong, as it only prints the cheese topping. Any hints?

Comment: You already tagged this quesiton with `arrays`. So have you considered reading a [tutorial about arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and using an array to save more than one Topping?

Comment: Well the Pizza only has one single `topping` field, what else do you expect?

Comment: You could also use a List

Comment: @Enrico no, I got it. OP wants multiple toppings on a pizza, but there is only one field for a single topping. That is the obvious place to start changing the code.

Comment: edited the pizza class with new info.

Comment: @toxette the `new Toppings[]{Toppings.tomatosauce, Toppings.cheese};` needs to be in the `main` method. Now you only need to change the `toString` method to `return "Toppings: " + Arrays.toString(toppings);`

Comment: Your constructor takes an array of Toppings, but you're not using the parameter for anything. Instead you're constructing the same toppings for every pizza. Also, in your main method, you're instantiating Pizza with only one topping, which wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public class Pizza{

    private Toppings[] toppings;

    public Pizza(Toppings ...toppings){
        this.toppings = toppings;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Toppings: " + Arrays.toString(toppings);
    }

}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza(Toppings.cheese, Toppings.tomato);
        System.out.println(pizza);
    }
}

enum Toppings { cheese, tomato }
```

or

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza(new Toppings[]{Toppings.cheese, Toppings.tomato});
```

instead and change the constructor of `Pizza`:

```
public Pizza(Toppings[] topping) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding (new Toppings[] {...}) saved me , thank you!